# What object should I pass to a function that requires Void! in a parameter? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

I am using the contract ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview() to capture a little image.

```
private val cameraLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) { bitmap ->
                view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageOutput)?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
```

When I try to launch the Activity for Result, I realise that this contract requires a Void! object as a input. So that, The only way I can launch this activity is passing "null" as a parameter, what I think is not very beautiful.

```
cameraLauncher.launch(null)
```

I've tried passing "Nothing", "Unit" but the type mismatch.

What is the right way to do so?

The header of that function would be

```
public void launch(Void input)
```

Comment: Have you tried `cameraLauncher.launch()`? There's a Kotlin extension in `activity-ktx` that handles this case for you.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Oh thanks :) I've tried it and it works. Before posting the question, I did not import `activity-ktx`, so this extension function was not available. With this library, this code is more beautiful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Java docs,

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword `void`

Because the Void class can not be instantiated, the only value you can pass to a method with a Void type parameter, is `null`.

The reason this is even required in the first place is because all the ActivityContracts inherit from the base `abstract class ActivityResultContract<I, O>` which expects two data types for input (`I`) and output(`O`). Since `TakePicturePreview` doesn't require any input, it uses `Void?` to just make up for that.

Now to answer,

> What is the right way to do so?

Passing `null` is the right (and the only) way here.